# Passing data from tJavaRow to tJava in Talend

Tags: java, talend

I'm using Talend for an integration, I'm wondering it is it possible to pass data from `tJavaRow` to `tJava` components.

For example:

`tJavaRow` component:

```
String check = input_row.foo;

if( check.contains("Yes")){
    String ret  = "OK";
    return ret; 
}
```

`tJava` component:

```
System.out.println(ret);
```

Is there a way to print `ret`, which is a result of a computation of a previous component inside a next component?

Comment: Simply use the globalMap, `globalMap.put("ret", ret);` and in the tJava you can recover the value `globalMap.get("ret")` but `tJava` is not executed in a main flow.

Comment: I don't understand this -> `but tJava is not executed in a main flow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the `globalMap` or a `tSetGlobalMap`

```
globalMap.put("ret", ret);
```

and recover it with

```
globalMap.get("ret");
```

/!\ IMPORTANT /!\

But note that if you use a `tJava` in a main flow like

```
tRowGenerator > row1 > tJava > row2> tLogRow
```

- `tRowGenerator` generating 10 rows for 1 to 10
- `tJava` like `System.out.println("foo");`
- `tLogRow` print the numeric value

The output will be

```
foo
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**The code in `tJava` is only executed once before the first row is even generated**. Checking the generated code, you can see

```
System.out.println("foo");
....
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    logrow.print(i);
}
```

Comment: @OiRc, if this is answering your problem, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).If this is not enough, don't hesitate to ask for more information (on the actual question).